# Определить конец листа формата А4

Tags: print, печать, tcpdf, формат

Делаю плагин печатных форм. Нужно как-то определить конец листа, чтобы разрывать таблицу для счетов-фактур, накладных итд, чтобы вывести промежуточный итог. Да и не красиво получается когда таблица разрывается на середине. При этом желательно не использовать яваскрипт т.к. сгенерированные в html страницы сразу же конвертируются в pdf при помощи библиотеки tcpdf

Comment: Тег **PHP** тут лишний.  
**PHP** это серверный язык, ему не ведомо как будет все выглядит. Вам нужно смотреть в настройки самого **TCPDF**.

Comment: @borodatych Если он изготавливает pdf, то ведомо. Ибо pdf и задуман, что бы сразу было ведомо что и где и никаких разногласий по этому поводу ни у кого не было. Это html всяк по своему крутит, а pdf ни-ни

Comment: Я когда-то видел функцию в php, которой задаешь текст, шрифт, размер шрифта, ширину текста, а она выдавала высоту. Сейчас как ни гуглю, не могу найти. Теоретически я могу для каждой печатной формы вычислить предельное количество строк в таблице. Но тут нужно знать в одну строчку у нас идет текст или нет. Никак не могу нормально сформулировать для гугля что я ищу. А может и другие способы есть...

Comment: @Andrew Godin, В чем суть проблемы, я недопонял? **TCPDF** умеет разделять на A4. Сгуглил [tcpdf a4](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_028.phps) - не оно?

Comment: Ну вот я формирую документ. В нем 133 товарных позиции. Мне нужно знать в какой момент закрыть тег <table>, вывести промежуточный итог и вставить $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4')

Comment: Тег `<table>` - это HTML тег. Зачем вы его используете, PHP о нем ни чего не знает?

Comment: Я сначала создаю шаблоны для smarty на html, потом их конвертирую. Каждая печатная форма имеет возможность создавать темы дизайна и редактировать шаблоны т.к. у каждой организации свои требования к документам. Поэтому все изначально делается на html, потом конвертируется в pdf.

Comment: Наверное формируется html, и из него получают pdf, В css есть свойства, подсказывающие как печатать элементы документа. Где-то вставить разрыв страницы, где-то избегать разрыва. `page-break-*`. Есть свойства, которые указывают сколько строк абзаца должно оставаться на старой или новой странице (висячие строки?). Может и для таблиц что-то есть.

Comment: Если таблицу не разорвать самому, то tcpdf проглатывает одну строку.

Comment: Размеры строк таблицы заранее не известны? Вы же можете задать размер шрифта, всякие отступы, межстрочные интервалы в миллиметрах например. Тогда вам точно будут известны все размеры и можно точно узнать на какой строке вставить разрыв. Но это только если высота строки не меняется. То что пишет Андрев Годин, Только функции никакое не надо.

Comment: Попробуйте [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846164/tcpdf-html-table-and-page-breaks).

Comment: <table nobr="true"> - это уже какое-то решение. Для начала можно его использовать, а потом уже думать как можно более точно вычислять размеры. borodatych, большое спасибо!

Comment: Гугл благодарите)). Просьба, как решите, отпишитесь, пожалуйста, ответом.

Comment: <tr nobr="true"> не помогает

Comment: `<tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">...` вот такое попробуйте

Comment: Ещё описывается такая метода. Запомнить текущую страницу. Стартовать транзакцию. Нарисовать строку таблицы. Посмотреть не произошёл ли переход на новую страницу. Если нет - то всё нормально. Закоммитить транзакцию. Если нет - откатить транзакцию, как будто ничего не рисовали, Теперь добавить новую страницу и на ней рисовать эту строку таблицы

Comment: <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;"> частичнео помогло http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/16/0417/h_1460913832_5788644_2ac77cc97d.png

Comment: По поводу транзакций я уже пару часов думаю над этим. Это сломает мне всю стректуру шаблонов. Но похоже другого выхода нет. Т.е. мне придется сделать шаблон шапки печатной формы и шаблон подвала. А так же шаблон единичной строки товара. Сначала я добавляю шапку, потом товары по одному пока не достигну конца страницы.

Comment: Почему частично? Строка же на одной странице остаётся. Что не так не понятно. Что таблица сдвинулась? Может там надо отступы всякие настроить, поля печати, чтобы было чёткое указание какие использовать, а то автоматика с потолка берёт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямого решения я не нашел. Придумал костыль. Не буду приводить мой никому не нужный код, опишу словами:

Шаблон нужно разделить на блоки. Хедер, футер, и та часть, которая в цикле.
Добавляем блоки через $tcpdf->writeHTMLCell()

Создаем еще один экземпляр класса tcpdf, добавляем страницу, сохраняем $tcpdf->GetY()
Добавляем очередной блок, и снова $tcpdf->GetY()
Вычисляем разницу и проверяем не достигли ли мы предела страницы. Если достигли, то создаем новую страницу. Разрушаем временный класс.

И только после этого пишем $tcpdf->writeHTMLCell()

Костыль не очень изящный, жрет много ресурсов, но зато можно даже вывести подытог на каждой странице во всяких накладных и прочих списках.